# Split an Array with multiple file into multiple arrays with similar file names

Tags: powershell

So I have

```
Array = [testfile001_TR1,
testfile001_TR2,
testfile001_TR3,
testfile002_TR1,
testfile002_TR2,
testfile002_TR3]
```

I would like to split the above Array into multiple arrays

```
Array[0] = testfile001_tr1,testfile001_tr2,testfile001_tr3 

Array[1] = testfile002_tr1,testfile002_tr2,testfile002_tr3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code and explain what is not working as expected.

Comment: ... and you might explain what your actual goal is ... there might be better options than you think of at the moment. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the response, but I'm so new at this that I'm not sure where to begin.  I've been searching the web, but haven't really found what I was looking for. I have a folder containing 10-20 files that are named in the similar format as above. 

Currently when the script is executed, it opens a Windows dialog allowing me to select files that I want to process.  I select the files and the script processes the audio files.
What I'd like to do is select all the files in the folder > split the files into their ownseparate Arrays and then process each array consisting of 3 files each.

Comment: If I got you right it should be enogh to sort the files  according to their filename and process them in chunks of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right  something like this should work actually.

First you get all desired files from the directory you specify sorted by their file names:

```
$FileList = 
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\sample' -Filter 'testfile*.mp3' | 
        Sort-Object -Property BaseName
```

The result would be something similar to this:

```
$FileList = 
    'testfile001_TR1',
    'testfile001_TR2',
    'testfile001_TR3',
    'testfile002_TR1',
    'testfile002_TR2',
    'testfile002_TR3',
    'testfile256_TR1',
    'testfile256_TR2',
    'testfile256_TR3'
```

Now you can use a for loop to process the files in chunks of 3 as you like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $FileList.Count; $i += 3) {
    "Chunk Number '$(($i/3) + 1 )'"
    "Do something meaningful with the file #1 '$($FileList[$i])'"
    "Do something meaningful with the file #2 '$($FileList[$i + 1])'"
    "Do something meaningful with the file #3 '$($FileList[$i + 2])'"
}
```

The sample output would look like this:

```
Chunk Number '1'
Do something meaningful with the file #1 'testfile001_TR1'
Do something meaningful with the file #2 'testfile001_TR2'
Do something meaningful with the file #3 'testfile001_TR3'
Chunk Number '2'
Do something meaningful with the file #1 'testfile002_TR1'
Do something meaningful with the file #2 'testfile002_TR2'
Do something meaningful with the file #3 'testfile002_TR3'
Chunk Number '3'
Do something meaningful with the file #1 'testfile256_TR1'
Do something meaningful with the file #2 'testfile256_TR2'
Do something meaningful with the file #3 'testfile256_TR3'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Splitting an array into *two* arrays (collections)** by a given criterion can be achieved with the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```
$array = 
  'testfile001_TR1',
  'testfile001_TR2',
  'testfile001_TR3',
  'testfile002_TR1',
  'testfile002_TR2',
  'testfile002_TR3'

# Note: $coll1 and $coll2 aren't technically *arrays*, but for
#       most purposes behave like ones.
$coll1, $coll2 = $array.Where({ $_ -like 'testfile001*' }, 'Split')
```

Efficiently **splitting into *multiple* collections** requires extra work, using a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) and an efficiently extensible collection (list) type, [`[System.Collections.Generic[T]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1):

```
$array = 
  'testfile001_TR1',
  'testfile001_TR2',
  'testfile001_TR3',
  'testfile002_TR1',
  'testfile002_TR2',
  'testfile002_TR3',
  'testfile003_TR1',
  'testfile003_TR2',
  'testfile003_TR3'

$lists = 
 [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new(),
 [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new(),
 [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

switch -Wildcard ($array) {
  'testfile001*' { $lists[0].Add($_) }
  'testfile002*' { $lists[1].Add($_) }
  default        { $lists[2].Add($_) }
}
```